# jQuery slice() Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use jQuery `slice()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".this").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");        
});
```

This display as default window size.

How to set this for `min-width 320px` and `max-width 480px` window with another margin option?

Comment: um, unclear what you are asking here!

Comment: Are you wanting to change margins as the page width changes?

Comment: this might be helpful to you: http://designedbythomas.co.uk/blog/how-detect-width-web-browser-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia).

You write it the same way as CSS media queries:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px)')) {
        $(".this").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "20px");
    } else {
        $(".this").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
    }
});
```

Comment: Oooow, that's what the OP meant!

Comment: I was also understanding this way first. But seeing answer of @Cerbrus the OP is wanted to do that!

Comment: @C-link: I'm not so sure, you can read the question both ways.

Comment: Just seen this `another margin option?`

Answer (score 4):

You can apply multiple css properties like this:

```
.css({
    "margin":"10px",
    "min-width":"320px",
    "max-width":"480px"
});
```